# XLSX Populate: "Error: Can't find end of central directory : is this a zip file?" - in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, xlsx

### XLSX Populate: "Error: Can't find end of central directory : is this a zip file?" - in Angular

I'm having a hard time with a error being thrown by Angular when using XSLX Populate.

#### Error:

```
main.c8862013051d6e746aa1.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Can't find end of central directory : is this a zip file ? If it is, see https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/read_zip.html
Error: Can't find end of central directory : is this a zip file ? If it is, see https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/read_zip.html
    at u.readEndOfCentral (main.c8862013051d6e746aa1.js:1)
    at u.load (main.c8862013051d6e746aa1.js:1)
    at main.c8862013051d6e746aa1.js:1
    at e.invoke (polyfills.f6ae3e8b63939c618130.js:1)
    at Object.onInvoke (main.c8862013051d6e746aa1.js:1)
    at e.invoke (polyfills.f6ae3e8b63939c618130.js:1)
    at t.run (polyfills.f6ae3e8b63939c618130.js:1)
    at polyfills.f6ae3e8b63939c618130.js:1
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.f6ae3e8b63939c618130.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.c8862013051d6e746aa1.js:1)
    at j (polyfills.f6ae3e8b63939c618130.js:1)
    at j (polyfills.f6ae3e8b63939c618130.js:1)
    at polyfills.f6ae3e8b63939c618130.js:1
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.f6ae3e8b63939c618130.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.c8862013051d6e746aa1.js:1)
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.f6ae3e8b63939c618130.js:1)
    at t.runTask (polyfills.f6ae3e8b63939c618130.js:1)
    at d (polyfills.f6ae3e8b63939c618130.js:1)
    at t.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.f6ae3e8b63939c618130.js:1)
    at _ (polyfills.f6ae3e8b63939c618130.js:1)
```

My code consists in a Reader for Templates .XSLX files and then populate using data from a Firecloud Database.

#### Code:

```
exportData() {
    var selectedCert = this.selection.selected;
    var filepath = "";
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   
    switch (selectedCert.map((data => data.IDTipo)).toString()) {
        case "R101180813F":
          filepath = "src/app/preciso-explorer/templates/preciso-medidor-pressao.xlsx";
          break;
        case "R05150707I-3":
          filepath = "src/app/preciso-explorer/templates/preciso-termohigrometro3.xlsx";
          break;
        case "R100180915F":
          filepath = "src/app/preciso-explorer/templates/preciso-vidraria-graduada.xlsx";
          break;
        case "R101181123A":
          filepath = "src/app/preciso-explorer/templates/preciso-medidor-pressao102.xlsx";
          break;
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET", filepath, true);
      xmlhttp.responseType = "arraybuffer";
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        console.log("xmlHttp: stateChange ok");
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
          console.log("xmlHttp: State 4 ok");
          if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            console.log("xmlHttp: Status 200 ok");
          
            XLSX.fromDataAsync(xmlhttp.response).then(workbook => {
              console.log("dataAsync ok");
              if (selectedCert != null) {
                var id = (selectedCert.map(data => data["ID"]).toString());
                switch (selectedCert.map((data => data.IDTipo)).toString()) {
                  case "R101180813F": [...]
```

I've already tried storing the files somewhere else but no success after multiple tries.

Comment: As per the docs `xmlhttp.open("GET", filepath, true);` should be `xmlhttp.open("GET", serverfilefilepath, true);` something like this - `var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.open("POST", "stash.php", true);` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: It was working properly with GET and the file's path in xmlhttp's parameters. I think is a worse workaround to have a page returning the files to the XLSX function.

Comment: But It would be helpful to maintain those files elsewhere and get them when needed, I'm thinking about using firebase's storage.

Comment: Ok so you mean these are downloads and not really uploads? I will recommend you to use the form data for uploads, the example which I have used and know works. However, if you are fetching the template from the server, I am unsure of what's going on. What am I missing in the questions section?

Comment: Yeah, they are downloads. Sorry. I'm currently trying to use Firebase Storage to get those files but no success.

Comment: any update on a solution that would have worked for you?

Comment: I don't know what I did back then, but the problem was with something related to my code, what I do remember that I rebuilt the whole method and that worked.